# Sitefinity search index scope - add ihttphandler task

Tags: sitefinity

Is there is a way I can add an ihttphandler to the search index scope. I have a ihttphandler processrequest that collecting external data and then doing an updateIndex. But I wanted to see if I can trigger that when the re-index task is completed.

```
 public class ExternalIndexerHandler : IHttpHandler
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think you want to run your custom code on the ToPublishingPoint method, when it's done right?

Global.asax

```
            PublishingSystemFactory.UnregisterPipe(PageInboundPipe.PipeName);
            PublishingSystemFactory.RegisterPipe(PageInboundPipeCustom.PipeName, typeof(PageInboundPipeCustom));
```

Now the pipe...

```
    public class PageInboundPipeCustom : PageInboundPipe
    {
        public override void ToPublishingPoint()
        {
            //Index has completed, time to do whatever now...
            base.ToPublishingPoint();

            var itemsToAdd = new List<WrapperObject>();

            //Make sure its only running for a specific index
            if (this.PipeSettings.PublishingPoint.Name == "YourIndexName")
            {
                var externalStuff = this.GetExternalStuff();
                foreach (var s in externalStuff )
                {
                    var item = new AppendixIndexItem(s);
                    var itemToAdd = new WrapperObject(item);

                    Debug.WriteLine(item.IdentityField);

                    //Metadata... if needed
                    //itemToAdd.SetOrAddProperty("Tags", "Educational Material");
                    itemsToAdd.Add(itemToAdd);
                }

                if (itemsToAdd.Count > 0)
                {
                    this.PublishingPoint.AddItems(itemsToAdd);
                }
            }
        }

        public List<string> GetExternalStuff() {
           var items = new List<string>();
           
           //Callback to your external stuff?

           return items;
        }
    }
```

Is that what you're looking for?

[Steve McNiven-Scott](https://www.sitefinitysteve.com)

Comment: Why use `this.PublishingPoint.AddItems` vs `ServiceBus.ResolveService<ISearchService>().UpdateIndex` ? Is one better then the other?